# Zurb Foundation Sass not Compiling Completely

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

EDIT:
This problem occurs with sass 3.4.2. Using sass 3.2.13 works perfectly.
Did something change?

I have a fresh copy of Zurb Foundation checked out using `bower install foundation`.

When I try to use compass sass to compile it (`sass foundation.scss > foundation.css`), I get a stylesheet that is missing certain components like buttons.

```
> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

> scss --version
Sass 3.4.2 (Selective Steve)
```

Exact Steps taken:

1. `> bower install zurb/bower-foundation`
2. `> cd bower_components/foundation/scss`
3. `> scss foundation.scss > foundation.css`

Here is the output:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aecbc11a1cefb630a22c

Comment: Per the documentation, surely you should be using `bower install zurb/bower-foundation`?

Comment: Same issue for `bower install zurb/bower-foundation`

Comment: I'm not a Bower/Sass user, but those CLI calls look different to the ones posted **[here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html#cli)**. The `zurb/bower-foundation` comes from their GitHub Repo. Seems they can be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a smaller bug within Foundation (could maybe even pertain to the use of global variables).

These warnings/errors are surpressed in newer versions of Compass and SASS (shown is a error log from an older version of Sass/Compass output)

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 270 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss:
Assigning to global variable "$default-float" by default is deprecated.
In future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable.
If you want to assign to the global variable, use "$default-float: left !global" instead.
Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 271 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss:
Assigning to global variable "$opposite-direction" by default is deprecated.
In future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable.
If you want to assign to the global variable, use "$opposite-direction: right !global" instead.
Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.

DEPRECATION WARNING: The return value of index() will change from "false" to
"null" in future versions of Sass. For compatibility, avoid using "== false" on
the return value. For example, instead of "@if index(...) == false", just write
"@if not index(...)".
        on line  of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss, in `exports'
        from line 336 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss
        from line 5 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss
        from line 9 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss
        from line 9 of /resources/sass/screen.scss
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 13 of /bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss:
Assigning to global variable "$modules" by default is deprecated.
In future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable.
If you want to assign to the global variable, use "$modules: append($modules, $name) !global" instead.
Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.
```

What I did to remedy or fix this is to make an [gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) for the project containing Foundation, running an older version of Compass and Sass to mitigate the issue (this procedure requires RVM)

Gemfile (can be generated using `bundle init` )

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem "sass",  "3.3.14"
gem "compass",  "1.0.0"
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Best
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

We had to make some changes to the Command to create a new project and process for updating for 5.4.5/ In 5.4.4 you will not have any issues. We added a gemfile to use Sass 3.3 so that the project compiles and produces a deprecation warning.

More info here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/changelog.html

New commands if you are on Sass 3.4 and Compass 1.0 are:
Before running Compass watch, run 'bundle' **only once per project
then to compile - 'bundle exec compass watch'

This is so you dont have to downgrade Sass versions

To know what Sass version you have
Sass -v
compass -v